# Where is wallet rpc api documentation?

Tags: wallet, rpc, keosd

Reading through the nodeos RPC API docs on the eos.io website, there are many different API's documented: Chain, History, Net, Producer, DBSize. And the docs for many of the RPC calls in these tell me to "use /v1/wallet/sign_transaction to get the right signature" etc.

But where can I find the wallet RPC API docs to use sign_transaction and other related functions? This is not on the same page, or anywhere else on the internet as far as I can tell. The wallet API seems to have moved to keosd but cannot find any RPC docs for that either.

So where can I find the docs for the EOS wallet API or is there some other alternative I should use?

Comment: possibly best you can find right now is the [source code](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/plugins/wallet_plugin)

Comment: huh. i was hoping not. parsing http server setups and request parsing from c++ code is not really my strong points..

Comment: turns out it was removed altogether so no need for c++ code parsing (yet) :P

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to RPC API document of v1.1.0 which had wallet APIs before.

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.1.0/reference

Comment: Thanks. Did not think to look at previous versions. At least it has some docs, although I see the RPC docs in general are pretty limited. Just lists the URL with very limited information on the parameters, and a JSON for reply with little to no explanation as well. It's a start I guess.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [release notes of v1.2.0](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/releases/tag/v1.2.0), the `wallet_api_plugin` has been removed:

> - it is no longer possible to run the `wallet_plugin` or `wallet_api_plugin`
>     as part of `nodeos`. This configuration has not been recommended for
>     many versions as it places private information in the same process
>     space as unrelated RPCs and the execution environment for untrusted
>     code (WebAssembly). This release officially removes the support.

You could possibly use [`eosjs`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs) for signing transactions depending on your requirements.

Comment: Yeah it is removed from nodeos but seems to have moved to keosd. When I start keosd, it prints out "starting wallet_api_plugin", "add api url: /v1/wallet/sign_transaction", etc. Can also access those URL's but need the docs for parameters. The RPC API docs still reference it, while no mention where to find it. That's a mess. Have to look into eosjs, although would prefer to avoid extra components..

Comment: yeah I don't think `keosd` api has ever been documented, just `nodeos`

Answer (score 1):

Ok that is true that wallet_plugin has been removed from the nodeos but kleosd is still using that and we can still perform any rpc of wallet operations suppose your keosd is running on the port 9999 and you want to create a wallet using rpc call you can do that by following operation using curl.

```
curl -X POST   http://127.0.0.1:9999/v1/wallet/create   -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'  -d '"mywallet"'
```

For reference you can use https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.1.0/reference